# How to create a dialog box or control bar , it always pop at the top of all the programs?

Tags: windows-phone-7, always-on-top

Is there a way to create a dialog box or control bar,  it always on top of all the programs,like the volume setting control bar that you press the volume hard key ?  I want to do a wp7 program to simulate the hard key,using c# . Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the programming language you are using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security model of Windows Phone 7 replaces various restrictions on what your application can do. One of these restrictions is that only one application can be running at any one point in time. This means it is not possible to run your applications 'above' others. Features such as the volume control pop-up are part of the WP7 OS and have not been created using the Silverlight framework that we, as developers, have access to.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the "TopMost" property to True

```
form.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: TopMost is a property of a WinForms form. The question is about WP7 which uses the Silverlight framework.